# How to make autosliding carousel thumbnail change background image when active

Tags: javascript, typescript

my question has 3 parts. Any assistance with any part of this JS problem would be greatly appreciated. I am attempting to learn and comprehend JS by trial and error.

[image]

I've created this nice looking travel landing page, https://portfolioprime.github.io/Nature%20carousel/glidejs.html with a thumbnail carousel which uses Glide.js, which is really cool and works well. The carousel moves to the left and has arrow buttons to manually control the slide.

But I've been trying to implement a vanilla JS carousel slider,but I am failing miserably. Been struggling for 2 days and the best I can achieve is getting a single carousel item moving left and right. See https://portfolioprime.github.io/Nature%20carousel/.

What I'd like is to get the carousel sliding left automatically, with arrow buttons to manually control the slider.

I'm targeting all the carousel-items with `querySelectorAll('.carousel-items')` and adding `left:-274px` to the carousel container `glide__slides`.

Here's my JS code.

```
// var & event-listener buttons
document.querySelector(".left").addEventListener("click", slideLeft);

document.querySelector(".right").addEventListener("click", slideRight);

// Function slide left
function slideLeft(left) {
  document.querySelector('.glide__slides').style.left = left;
}
// Function slide left
function slideRight(right) {
  document.querySelector('.glide__slides').style.left = right;
}
```

Secondly, I'd like to have an active carousel-item, which when active automatically changes the background Image.

Right now I have the `hero.style.background = var;` and I've got it changing onclick with `onclick = function('01.jpg')` on each carousel item.

Here's the code.

```
// Change Hero Img
 function heroChange(hmmm) {
  var hero = document.querySelector('.hero');
  hero.style.background = hmmm;
 }
```

So I guess I would add EventListeners to the carousel-items and add an active class to the carousel-item like so,

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-items');

function changeBgImg() {
  slides.forEach(s => s.classList.remove('active');
  this.classList.add('active');

//change the bg image === this
//But I have no idea how to do that

}
```

Thirdly I've got the content, background and carousel indicators using the same functions above but it seems like really dirty code. The HTML has each `.carousel-item`, there are ten of them, calling 4  functions each. It looks like this:

```
      <div class="glide hero-carousel">
        <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
          <ul class="glide__slides">

            <li class="glide__slide carousel-item" 
              onclick="heroChange('url(images/02.jpg) bottom/cover no-repeat'); 
              number('01'); 
              h4('Destination Shire'); 
              h1('Valley<br> of Dreams');">

              <div class="carousel-text">
                <p>Destination Shire</p>
                <h3>Valley<br> of Dreams</h3>
              </div>

            </li>

            <li class="glide__slide carousel-item" 
              onclick="heroChange('url(images/03.jpg) bottom/cover no-repeat'); 
              number('02'); 
              h4('Destination Westwood'); 
              h1('Misty<br> Woodlands');">

              <div class="carousel-text">
                <p>Destination Westwood</p>
                <h3>Misty<br> Woodlands</h3>
              </div>

            </li>

         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
```

So it looks pretty yucky. It works though, but I would love to find a more elegant way of achieving this by putting all of these functions into one function that does each part in sequence.

Lastly, I'd want to get transition on-click animations going but that's another kettle of fish entirely.

So that's it. Whew!

Thanks for taking the time guys, I appreciate it. Any help you can provide is going to make me a better designer. There are actually a bunch of projects I have will benefit from the answers.

If you can provide help with at least Part 2 & 3: cleaning up the code into 1 function and getting the bg-image changing on the active class that would be a big big help.

There's just so much that JS can do and I'm not finding the answers on Google and youTube.

Thank you again.

An Update:

I have edited the slider by by using margin-left as shown by this question:

[vanilla javascript carousel not sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233095/vanilla-javascript-carousel-not-sliding)

```
// var & event-listener buttons
document.querySelector(".left").addEventListener("click", slideLeft);
document.querySelector(".right").addEventListener("click", slideRight);


let marginLeft = 0;
const slides = document.querySelector('.glide__slides');

// Function slide left
function slideLeft() {
  marginLeft += 264;
  slides.style.marginLeft = marginLeft + 'px';
  console.log(getComputedStyle(slides).marginLeft);
}
// Function slide Right
function slideRight() {
  marginLeft -= 264;
  slides.style.marginLeft = marginLeft + 'px';
  console.log(getComputedStyle(slides).marginLeft);
}
```

This has now got the carousel moving manually 1 slide at a time.
Still not fully understanding why my previous code above didn't work. If anyone can explain that to me that would be great.

I'm still left with some issues:

1. Autosliding and looping at the end of the slides.
2. Having the active slider change the background automatically. At this point it only changes onclick.
3. Finding a way to tidy up the function calls and functions.

Comment: It's possible that my answer to this question [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861444/vanilla-javascript-css-image-slider-not-working-properly/63869623#63869623 may be of interest - it is pure javascript/css and allows for infinite scrolling. I will come back to look at your question in more detail tomorrow.

Comment: I have put a partial answer up, a way of getting the yucky code created at run time and making it simpler to maintain a slider - to add, remove or change the order of slides. I will look at the using native JavaScript to create an infinite slider later today. Meanwhile, could you say what you want to happen when a slide is clicked, and when an arrow is clicked if the slider is already moving automatically?

Comment: Thanks, @A Haworth, I'll look into you link above.

Comment: Thanks, @A Haworth, I'll look into you link above. I would say when a slide is clicked the .hero background image should change. When a button is clicked the slide should move in that direction by one slide. What would be optimum is for the slider to pause scrolling on slide or btn hover. Have a look at <https://portfolioprime.github.io/Nature%20carousel/index-autoslide-left.html>. I have it auto-sliding here, but the its not resetting the slider after the final slide. And also not pausing.

Comment: Summary: the slider starts off automatically with slides going from right to left and there's a pause when one gets to the left and at that point the background image should change (?). If the user either hovers on a slide or on a btn (is this one of the arrows?) the slider pauses. Clicking an arrow moves by one slide in the direction of the arrow (and stops any autosliding??). The whole thing should be a continuous loop. It can all be done with CSS animations - reasonably simply. I will update my answer in about 2 hours.

Comment: Yes sir, that sums it up. Yes to all except I would not like to stop any autosliding. I think it would be sufficient to have autosliding pause on hover. The only issue I foresee is the problem of no-hover on mobile devices, but hey, can't have it all I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks for various ideas on how to simplify code and how to use native JavaScript to create a slider that rolls continuously.

The code originally used glider and it may be something simpler would be sufficient to get the desired result, for example using animationend event to change the background when a slide gets to the left hand side. However, eating the elephant slowly I'll tackle the yucky code (part 3) first.

Although the HTML looks rather daunting, 4 calls on a click for every li element for example, it is currently what is required so let's investigate creating it at run time. This gives us more easily maintainable code. For example, if we want to remove a slide, or alter the order of slides or add one we can just alter the slider array defined below and JavaScript will do the rest.

Part 1 of the question asked about sliding. We slide the whole ul element using CSS animation defined something like this, where 33vw is the total width of a slide (inc. margins/padding)

```
@keyframes sliding0 {
  0% { left: 0; }
  30% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -33vw; }
}
```

and we add an event listener to the element to trap animationend events because when the ul has slid one slide's width we want to change the hero image, and we want to put the slide that has just disappeared onto the back of the infinie sliding will work. We then set the animation running again.

See the snippet for details on how this and other events are dealt with. It also shows how the changeHero function can work which was part 2 of the question. Note, the snippet works more or less in the SO environment, though occasionally hover action is partially ignored. Running the code on your own machine it should be fine though.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

@keyframes sliding0 {
  0% { left: 0; }
  30% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -33vw; }
}

@keyframes sliding1 {
  0% { left: 0; }
  30% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -33vw; }
}

body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
div .glide_track {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
  position:relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 330vw;
  height:100vh;
  animation-name: sliding0;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  float:left;
  width: 32vw;
  height:30vw;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 1vw;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>

// we put the two lots of text and the image url for each slide in an array in the order they are to be shown
// this makes it easier to maintain when you want to add or remove a slide or change their order
// we only have one slider at the moment but this makes it more general

// these are the offsets in the array describing a slide. Done as indexes rather than named as easier to set up sliders array
const img = 0;
const text1 = 1;
const text2 = 2;

const sliders = [
  [
    ['https://ahweb.org.uk/boxfordmosaic.jpg','Shire','Valley<br> of Dreams'],
    ['https://ahweb.org.uk/gear-in-turbine-house-reading.jpg','Westwood','Misty Woodlands'],
    ['https://ahweb.org.uk/tricycle-in-abbey-ruins.jpg','Shire','Valley<br> of Dreams'],
    ['https://ahweb.org.uk/boxfordmosaic.jpg','Shire','Valley<br> of Dreams'],
    ['https://ahweb.org.uk/gear-in-turbine-house-reading.jpg','Westwood','Misty Woodlands'],
    ['https://ahweb.org.uk/tricycle-in-abbey-ruins.jpg','Shire','Valley<br> of Dreams'],
    ['https://ahweb.org.uk/boxfordmosaic.jpg','Shire','Valley<br> of Dreams'],
    ['https://ahweb.org.uk/gear-in-turbine-house-reading.jpg','Westwood','Misty Woodlands'],
    ['https://ahweb.org.uk/tricycle-in-abbey-ruins.jpg','Shire','Valley<br> of Dreams'],
    ['https://ahweb.org.uk/tricycle-in-abbey-ruins.jpg','Shire','Valley<br> of Dreams']
  ]
];

// go through each slider and create its outer divs and its ul element
sliders.forEach(createSlider);

function createSlider(slider,sliderno) {
  const div1 = document.createElement('DIV');
  const div2 = document.createElement('DIV');
  const ul = document.createElement('UL');

  div1.classList.add("glide","hero-carousel");
  div2.classList.add("glide_track");
  div2.setAttribute("data-glide-el","track");

  div1.appendChild(div2);
  div2.appendChild(ul);
  document.body.appendChild(div1);

  ul.classList.add("glide__slides");
    
  ul.addEventListener("animationend", animationEnd);
 
  slider.forEach(createLi);

  function createLi(slide,slideNo) {
    const li = document.createElement('LI');
    li.classList.add("glide__slide","carousel-item");
    li.style.backgroundImage='url('+slide[img]+')';
    li.addEventListener("click",slideClicked);
    li.addEventListener("mouseover",slideHovered);
    li.addEventListener("mouseout",slideUnhovered);
    
    li.setAttribute('data-slideno','0' + slideNo);//! needs generalising if you have >10 slides !

    ul.appendChild(li);

    const div = document.createElement('DIV');
    const p = document.createElement('P');
    const h3 = document.createElement('H3');

    p.innerHTML = slide[text1];
    div.appendChild(p);
    h3.innerHTML = slide[text2];
    div.appendChild(h3);

    li.appendChild(div);
  }
}

// this is for testing, in real version use whatever required (i.e. whichever element is to have the hero image)
function ahHeroChange(backgroundImage) {  
  document.body.style.background = backgroundImage + " bottom/cover no-repeat";
}

function slideClicked(event) {
  var slide = event.target;
  var slideNo = slide.getAttribute('data-slideno');
  
  // make the hero image the same as the slide's
  ahHeroChange(slide.style.backgroundImage);
  
/* I don't know what these functions do - they were executed in the original on a click 

  number(slideno);
  h4(slide.firstElementChild.querySelector('p').innerHTML);// text1 of the slide is passed to h4
  h1(slide.firstElementChild.querySelector('h3').innerHTML;// text2 of the slide is passed to h1

*/
}

function slideHovered(event) {
  var slide = event.target;
  var slider = slide.parentElement;
  slider.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
  ahHeroChange(slide.style.backgroundImage);
}

function slideUnhovered(event) {
  var slide = event.target;
  var slider = slide.parentElement;
  
  //restore the hero image to the first one in the slider
  ahHeroChange(slider.firstElementChild.style.backgroundImage);
  
  //get the animation running again
  slider.style.animationPlayState = 'running'; 
}

function animationEnd(event) {
   //find the element that was clicked (it will be a ul element representing a slider)
   var slider = event.target;
   
  //take the first slide off the list and put it back at the end
  slider.append(this.firstElementChild);
  
  //change the hero image to the slide which is now the leftmost - use modified heroChange in the final version
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = this.firstElementChild.style.backgroundImage;
  
  // toggle the animationName (to an identical keyframes action) to force the animation to start again
  slider.style.animationName='sliding'+(Number(event.animationName.replace('sliding',''))+1)%2;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your succinct summary and the detail you've put into your explanations. Much much appreciated. I am currently setting this up. Will post my progress updates.

Comment: I have got your code above working now. See <https://portfolioprime.github.io/Nature%20carousel/index-new-try.html> , although I don't fully understand it, I have learnt a lot from it, ie. `createElement` and `appendChild`. I have removed some glider.js styles and div to simplify it slightly.

Comment: I have some questions though. Why create and nest `function creatLi()` inside `function createLis` instead of just continuing to create them in the top function? And can you explain `"slideClicked(this,"+slideno+")` this code and `function slideClicked(slide,slideno)`? Sorry might seem like a really dumb question, just dont get this part.

Comment: I probably misnamed createLis since it's creating the whole thing (the divs and the ul) for a slider. sliders.forEach(createLis); steps through one slider at a time (I know you only need one at the moment but for the general case) and for each slider it creates the divs and ul. Would it be clearer if we called it createSlider. For each slider you then have to go through each slide creating its li element which is what slider.forEach(createLi) does. I could have used anonymous functions but I find them more difficult to read.

Comment: function slideClicked(slide,slideno) is the function which replaces your 4 functions - actually it's just putting them all into one function. I didn't interpret them in any way, it comes straight from what you had in each li element, it's just neater putting them together. "slideClicked(this,"+slideno+")" creates a string slideClicked(this,2) (in the case of slide number 2). This is the javascript call that will be made on a click (i.e. your 4 function calls all rolled into the one function slideClicked). The + sign in JS is used both to add numbers and to concatenate strings.

Comment: Ah, thank you for explaining `sliders.forEach(createLis)`. So I've tried playing with the functions abit, but I can only get the `numbers` function working.

Comment: here it is https://portfolioprime.github.io/Nature%20carousel/index-new-try.html

Comment: In this line `li.setAttribute("onclick","slideClicked(this,"+slideno+")");` is `slideno` a var that `this` inserts into? So could `slideno` be `carouselnumber` for instance? And is this where `slideno` is initialized?

Comment: In terms of the functions in `slideClicked()` I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: h4 is not defined`, `h1 is not defined`,`heroChange is not defined`

Comment: h1, h4 and heroChange are your functions, I don't know what they do (though I can guess at heroChange) - they are called in that function so they do whatever your original code does (which puts calls to them in each li. I think we will be asked to move to chat as this conversation is getting long.

Comment: I have altered the code to be clearer about slideno and so on and to introduce sliding using CSS animation and infinite looping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222239/discussion-between-wayne-r-hendricks-and-a-haworth).